# Configuring output table popup for geoprocessing widget

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, web-mapping, arcgis-flex-viewer

I have built a simple geoprocessing widget that produces a table (record set) as its final product. I am trying to simply change how and which fields are displayed. I am using Flex Viewer 3.5 and Arc Server 10.1.

Here is my output:
[image]

Basically I want to only show the Value and Acres field. I tried doing this through the flex viewer in while configuring the GP Widget, but it didn't have any popup configuration options.
[image]

Any ideas of where I can set these configurations? GP.xml perhaps?

Thanks in advanced.

Adam